# iCloud Implementation app in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, icloud

I need to develop an Application to store images in iCloud. In My case i have four Category and its album i need to add images for every album and thats stored in iCloud and also i will show it in application with image details.here i need suggestion to develop the app. iCloud three types of storage is there.

1.Key Value storage

2.Document based storage

3.core data based storage

in that which types i should use it? please help me.

I searched  lot in google and analyzed more about that still i can't able to decide. because i am beginner in iPhone app development. and i dont know the concept of Core Data.but here most of the sample app in document based  only.There is no Core data based sample application to store images in iCloud.

give some of use full tutorial and links about store more images  in iCloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Document based iCLoud implementation as it suits your needs. For more guide see these links 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/iCloud/iCloud.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: thanks you sir i will check it all the references and i will ask some doubt in http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1 i used but it creates same file name like photo.data how can i develop and also can't able to create 2nd file in iCloud but its creates locally fine. for  that how to create  with different file name